# Specify current grandchild route without current child route in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have one parent view and many child views. Is it possible to specify state for one of this child as for grandchild, but without specifying current child name in state and how?

So, in my configuration I want to have something like this:

```
.state("parent", {
    url: "" // Resulting url is /
})
.state("parent.child", {
    url: /ChildUrl // Resulting url is /ChildUrl/
})
.state("parent.{some param}.grandchild", {
    url: "" // Resulting url is /ChildUrl/
})
```

OR How to change one child view with another without changing url in browser without grandchild solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally solved it with removing `url` parameter in states configuration for parent view and child view which could be represented as a `grandchild`. It works in way that I need

Answer (score 0):

Use  inside the parent template.

```
<div class="parentTemplate">
  <h1>Parent Title</h1>
  <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
```

child1 template:

```
<div class="child1Template">
  <h1>Child1 Title</h1>
</div>
```

child2 template:

```
<div class="child2Template">
  <h1>Child2 Title</h1>
</div>
```

The state config:

```
.state("parent", {
    url: "",
    templateUrl: "templates/parent-template.html"
})
.state("parent.child1", {
    templateUrl: "templates/child1-template.html"
})
.state("parent.child2", {
    templateUrl: "templates/child2-template.html",
    params: { 'child2Param': 'Default' }
})
```

Going to parent.child1 or parent.child2 will be at / however the `<ui-view>` directive will be filled with the appropriate child templates. You do not need a URL to navigate between states. Inject $state into the controller with the navigation and use `$state.go('parent.child1')`. If you need parameters to be passed define them in the params property on each states and invoke the change in states with `$state.go('parent.child2', {'child2Param', someObject.withDynamicValue }.`

Comment: The problem is that I need to change url with one child, but not to change it with another child with keeping url of previous child. Thats why I'm thinking about grand child, but I don't know how to specify it correctly. And I'm also using `$state.go`

Comment: Doesn't it work if you add url to one state and not the other? It will go to state and then change window.location accordingly. Or, go to url and load the child state accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've solved my issue. I've posted an answer